# Validate presence of one of multiple attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In an multilingual application, a user can input their Chinese and English names. The user can input either or both, but must input at least one name.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :zh_name, :presence => true
  validates :en_name, :presence => true
  validates :fr_name, :presence => true
end
```

Since the built-in :validates_presence_of method can only validate both attributes at once, is there a way to validate the presence of at least one of many attributes in rails?

Like a magical, `validates_one_of :zh_name, :en_name, :fr_name`

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
validate :at_least_one_name

def at_least_one_name
  if [self.zh_name, self.en_name, self.fr_name].reject(&:blank?).size == 0
    errors[:base] << ("Please choose at least one name - any language will do.")
  end
end
```

Comment: What's that `blank` method on the array ? It does not seem to exist. Did you mean `blank?`. If so, it cannot be used like that neither.
I would rather do 
`if array.reject(&:blank?).size == 0`

Comment: to only check nil: `if [obj.attr1, obj.attr2].compact.size == 0` seems to check for what I need. either attr can be supplied but at least one must be present, else add the error message.  To check blank (nil or empty string) used ronnieonrails' approach above.

Comment: Regarding ronnieonrails comment: How about `if array.all?(&:blank?)` I think that's a little more readable.

Comment: @ronnieonrails - you're right, sorry, i made a typo.  I meant to type `compact_blank` which is actually just a convenience method i wrote for the Array class, so obviously that's no good either!  I replaced it with `.reject(&:blank?)`

Comment: Code style quibble: IMHO, usually it's recommended to not use self.method_name unless necessary.

Comment: @M.G.Palmer why is that?  I've always thought it was much more readable:  when you use just the method name on it's own then it's indistinguishable from a local variable name.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Ok I guess it depends on your editor. Mine highlights them differently, and so for me it's clear if it's local variable or method. And then it's less noise to omit "self."

Comment: I don't think it's good practise to make readability dependent on people using a specific editor or IDE.  And i think that "self." is signal rather than noise :)

Answer (score 12):

Taking @micapam's answer a step futher, may I suggest:

```
validate :has_a_name

def has_a_name
  unless [zh_name?, en_name?, fr_name?].include?(true)
    errors.add :base, 'You need at least one name in some language!'
  end
end
```

Comment: Upvoted as cleanest code; did you consider a guard clause? http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/rubocop/Rubocop/Cop/Style/GuardClause

Comment: @Rich, I've added a version using a guard clause. I'm not sure if it needs to return true, but thought it safer to make sure it does.

Comment: @Rich, The more I look at this, the more I prefer the non-guarded version. I don't think the unless clause obscures the purpose of the method. Also the main purpose of the method is to test if a name is present, the unless method is the part of the code doing that. The error.add is just doing something on failure. By using a guard clause, the code is implying that the purpose of has_a_name is to add an error, when in fact the purpose is to check if a name is present.

Comment: I agree, the happy path shouldn't be a quick exit via a guard clause. Well, unless, you called the method 'invalid_without_name' then the guard clause would make more sense. Feel free to remove the guard clause example - it's better to have one simple example and leave implementation details to the programmer.

Comment: @Rich, I've removed the guard clause. Interesting conversation though which made me look deeper into guard clauses - so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

just a quick shot out, you can pass a "if" or "unless" to the validator, maybe you can get it working this way. i have something like this in mind

```
validates :zh_name, :presence => { :if => (fr_name.blank? && en_name.blank?) }
```

Comment: You have to permute all the different combinations for each attribute. OP says validates "at least one of many attributes". A custom validator is probably better in this case.

Comment: @Ingenu Indeed. A general validator is desired.

Comment: yep, totally forgot that its now super easy to have your custom validator

Answer (score 2):

```
validate :has_a_name

def has_a_name
  unless [zh_name, en_name, fr_name].any?{|val| val.present? }
    errors.add :base, 'You need at least one name in some language!'
  end
end
```

Max Williams' answer is fine, but I didn't see the need to count hits when any? returns a boolean.