# Rails: validation on two fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

One quick question. I have two fields pick_up and delivery. I want user to enter one of the two fields while submitting form. Means:

```
 validates pick_up or delivery, :presence => :true.
```

At least one should be present.

How to write this validation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679943/validate-presence-of-one-of-multiple-attributes-in-rails

Answer (score 2):

validate :pickup_or_delivery

```
def pickup_or_delivery
  if [self.pick_up, self.delivery].compact.blank.size == 0
    errors[:base] << ("Please select one option")
  end
end
```

Comment: how about 
`errors[:base] << "Please select one option" if pick_up.blank? && delivery.blank?`

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple enough validation that I'd just do a one-liner:

```
validate { errors.add(:base, 'Please select one option') if pick_up.blank? && delivery.blank? }
```